# How to filter all Google Analytics reports for a specific search term

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to create a filter on a Google Analytics profile.  I'd like it to include only traffic that has come as a result of searching for a specific search term.

For example, imagine I'm interested only in people who have arrived at my site having searched for the word 'dog'.  I don't care about any other visitors, so I want all my reports to be filtered for people who have searched for 'dog' to get to the site.

I have tried this a few ways, but I'm not convinced they're working.  My latest attempt was the following:

**Edit filter**

- Filter type: Include
- Filter field: Referral
- Filter pattern: (\?|&)(q|p)=.*dog.*([^&]*)
- Case sensitive: no

At the moment, this appears to be letting through traffic that has not come from a search engine.  It would be great if someone could explain what I need to do to get it to work correctly!

Many thanks,

Katie

[P.S. I realise this may sound like a strange request, but it's partly to help me learn a bit more about filters]

Comment: This seems like a rather limiting filter, considering the rate at which search terms are not being provided.

Answer (score 0):

Add another Include filter where medium=organic

You could also do it using Advanced Segments instead of requiring to setup a new profile for each keyword :-)